# Not respond to changes in specific files using Dnotify

Tags: c, linux, filtering

I know that Dnotify is old and there is a new api called Inotify, but I have to work with linux kernel 2.6.9, so the only option is to use dnotify.

I have a basic program to watch a directory using dnotify, I'm watching for DN_CREATE and DN_DELETE events. The program works good, it respond to every change. In my callback function I start a python script which acts as a filter (there are several files in that directory and I need to detect changes only about few of them). In that filter I save the state of the directory (filelist) to a file, so I can latter make a diff of current and old state and detect what file was modified.

Everything was working great until we figured out that the change I have to respond doesn't always come from creating or deleting the files of interest, but also from changes in their content. So i added the DN_MODIFY bits, now it works as excepted, but I'm also getting 2 modify signals every second (which I filter out in the python script). The signals are received because in that directory there are 2 files to which is written every second by some external program I don't have reach.

Launching a python interpreter twice+ a second seems as a waste of cpu plus this notification is running on a systems where I cannot waste a lot of cpu because those are testing machines where are our tests performed.

So is there a way, to exlude those 2 files that change every second?

A few thoughts:

- Move the filter from python to C - this may by faster but it still be detecting two+ changes every second
- Create a link to a file of interest when it is created, and put this link into a separate directory and watch for changes in that directory, after the file is deleted  destroy the link and stop the watch program.

EDIT:
I tried that second thought and it did not work, because dnotify wasn't detecting changes to that file when written to from outside of watched directory

Does anybody have any other ideas or better yet solutions to this kind of problem?

Thanks

Comment: Please note that notifying 2 changes per second is not much, even for a low ressources computer.

If you're experiencing performance issues in Python, I'd suggest you first to compare with a C version.

Regarding exclusion, you could try symlinking and hardlinking, kernel might track them though, in any way, exclusion will always be possible by patching the kernel.

What about posting the code of your signal handler ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried hard and symlinking but it did not work, if I created the links in some other dir and watched that dir, it only notified me when the change was done thought the link(was written to link), also the first idea is not good, it don't eat a lot of cpu (0,3 - 2,0% C binary + python script) but it is still called twice a second. Which would equal to calling it from cron - this is what we wanted to avoid in the first place(we were calling it every 10 minutes, but that under some circumstances didn't work well). I'll paste the handler tomorrow, when I get to my work